# Batch file to save RDP redentials for a remote machine's local account

Tags: batch-file, cmd, network-programming, rdp

I am trying to run a script to set up auto-logging to servers. My issue is, the account is a local profile to the remote machine and am having issues.

**Script:**

```
@ECHO off
FOR /F %%i IN (IPs.txt) DO (
    ECHO =====================
    ECHO Starting for %%i
    cmdkey /generic:"%%i" /user:"local\user" /pass:"password"
    ECHO =====================

)
```

Using the above, RDP is not detecting local means local...

The IPs.txt file lists all the IP addresses of the servers. Only thing I can think of is to have another text file that houses the computer name, but I am just not sure how to go about that.

**Example:** cmdkey /generic:"%%i" /user:"%%hostname\user" /pass:"password"

Comment: To use a normal variable, you'd use the following syntax: `%HostName%`, `%ComputerName%` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a period (dot) for a local account. This may result in what you want.

```
cmdkey /generic:"%%i" /user:".\user" /pass:"password"
```

Or take your [pick of environmental variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) according to your needs... `%ComputerName%`, `%USERDOMAIN%`, `%USERDOMAIN_roamingprofile%`, `%LOGONSERVER%`.

*Example:* `cmdkey /generic:"%%i" /user:"%ComputerName%\user" /pass:"password"`

For an account local to the remote server, a simple unqualified username should work...

```
cmdkey /generic:"%%i" /user:"user" /pass:"password"
```

Other than that, if you need to resolve your remote server name based on an IP address, I suppose you could parse `ping -a %%i` or `nbtstat -A %%i`... or with DNS use [`nslookup`](https://ss64.com/nt/nslookup.html).

To incorporate one of these into your batch file, try something like this...:

```
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F %%i IN (IPs.txt) DO (
    ECHO =====================
    Echo Resolving IP Address %%i...
    set CurrentIP=%%i
    Call :ResolveIpAddress
    echo Resolved Name = !ipName!
    Echo Creating Credentials
    cmdkey /generic:"%%i" /user:"!ipName!\user" /pass:"password"
    ECHO =====================
)

pause

:ResolveIpAddress
For /F "tokens=2" %%a IN ('ping -n 1 -a %CurrentIP%') Do (set ipName=%%a && exit /b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The '.' does not work. Generic error that it has an incorrect username/password. The %ComputerName% pulls my PCs name, but the servers we are connecting to are remote and have different names.

Comment: @dwb Ok, so what about one of the other environmental variables I give there, or the link I added?

Comment: Wait, do you mean "local" to the server? Like <RermoteServerName>\<UserName>? Then you should only need `cmdkey /generic:"%%i" /user:"user" /pass:"password"` right? What happens if you RDP connect and logon without saved credentials, fill out the prompt, and click save... how do you fill it out in the prompt window and how do the credentials look when saved?

Comment: Yes, local to the server. Just using "user" has it prefill with the last domain used and will not default to local. When the creds are saved in RDP, it saves it with "ServerName\Username"

Comment: @dwb Ok, I see, well I'm not sure if it's the best solution but I suppose the fallback is to resolve your IP address to a server name. The strategy that comes to mind for me is to parse `ping` or `nbtstat`. I edited my answer to include a solution that does this within your original script.

Comment: @u8it, ping is a terrible tool for resolving machine names.  Most machines should never respond to a ping.  Use nslookup.

Comment: @jwdonahue That really depends on what you're doing and your setup. The OP doesn't say "web servers", just servers. They could be on some isolated network for all I know. I wouldn't be so extreme and state that ping is a terrible tool. So long as there's a response it's more fool proof than nslookup in that it gets the name directly from the computer, while nslookup requires DNS. But yes, I agree, `nslookup` should definitely be mentioned for the web scenario, I just didn't get the impression that that's what's going on here.